# I want to get a single database SQL string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I got a little problem with this:

```
readonly LoginMandant logon = new LoginMandant();
string query = "SELECT Name FROM tMandant WHERE Id_Mandant = " + userDetails.Id_Mandant + ";";

Session["MandantName"] = logon.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

and it returns:

```
System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1[System.String]
```

But why? I wanted a single string like "test" in there.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection - check out [Little Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you are using [SingleOrDefaultAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.singleordefaultasync?view=efcore-3.1) it will return a task object.

you should use [SingleOrDefault()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.singleordefault?view=netframework-4.8) instead of async if you want to get the string from database synchronously.

below should work in your case:

```
Session["MandantName"] = logon.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).SingleOrDefault();
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to `await` operations that are task-like, i.e.

```cs
Session["MandantName"] = await logon.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

however, this requires your code to be `async`; if it isn't, either make it `async` (but **not** `async void`), or look for a synchronous version of the API.

You should *probably* look into parameters, too; the code as shown is actively dangerous.

Answer (score 1):

Async will require you to await.

```
Session["MandantName"] = await logon.Database.SqlQuery<string>(query).SingleOrDefaultAsync();
```

However, the calling method also has to be an async (and its caller call await, and so on). **I highly recommend this**, however, if you are really short on time, you could do the SingleOrDefaultAsync().Result or simply call the SingleOrDefault(), however, it will block the execution until the database query completes.

**IMPORTANT: Avoid string concatenation for the query string. You are risking SQL injection.**